Sarkhan, Soul Aflame Becoming a dragon that entered
So I have Sarkhan, Soul Aflame as a copy of The Ur-Dragon that entered this turn. When Sarkhan attacks both Sarkhan and The Ur-Dragon's effects go on the stack, I choose to resolve Sarkhan first, draw the cards and put an Ancient Silver Dragon onto the battlefield. Could Sarkhan become Ancient Silver Dragon before combat damage is dealt?

You may be interested to learn that there are some cards which can turn into different cards before combat damage is dealt.  For example, the Lazav in my answer could activate his ability after blockers are declared and end up dealing damage to the opponent as a different creature.  Slightly different is Satoru Umezawa, who gives all of your creatures in hand the "ninjutsu" ability, allowing them to trade places with unblocked attackers.
https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=548547

No.
Sarkhan does not have the crucial piece of text "and it has this ability" (see Lazav, the Multifarious).  This means that it can only use the ability once per turn.  Therefore, it cannot become a copy of ASD, because it is a "The Ur-Dragon" and does not have the ETB trigger of regular Sarkhan.
